# Separately or individually, which can indicate one to one relationship?

Tags: adverbs

> The pair of cables are each connected to a different one of the pair of
> ports.

I am trying to rewrite the sentence above I created into a simpler form by using an adverb . Which of the following can reflect the correct meaning?

1. The pair of cables are **separately** connected to the pair of ports.
2. The pair of cables are **individually** connected to the pair of ports.

Comment: Each cable pair connects to each port pair.

Comment: I don't see much difference. Separate(ly) might be more common. Individually might mean that when you plug them in you do it one at a time, while separately means they are separated in space, but I'm not sure that's an important distinction. However it's possible for cables to be connected to two ports but not be separate/individual, e.g. if you have a more complex connector that mates with both ports.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be clear if you say
Each cable is connected to one of the two ports.

Comment: For some reasons, I need to use an adverb such as separately and individually .